# angular-bootstrap collapse table row animation not transitioning smoothly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I'm running into an issue with angular-bootstrap collapse directive and CSS. Basically when you add the directive "collapse" to a div it works fine. But when you try to expand/collapse a table row it seems to have some issues with the transition effect.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="dogCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Breed</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="dog in dogs">
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">{{dog.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{dog.breed}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">
          <h3>Pet details</h3>
          <p>some details about this pet.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('dogApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('dogCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.dogs = [
        {
            name: "Sparky",
            breed: "Parson Russell Terrier"
        }, {
            name: "Shep",
            breed: "German Shepard"
        }
    ];
});
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEoOBq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the height of a table cell is “the minimum height required by the content” (as in CSS 2.1 rules) I guess you can't animate the table row height.

Probably the workaround involves wrapping the content of the cell into a `div` element and animating this container as well.

This worked for me but I have not tested heavily:

```
      <tr ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0">
          <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <h3>Pet details</h3>
            <p>some details about this pet.</p>                
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I figured it was something simple but didn't want to dive to deep into it. Side note, if you don't want the top border to show you can easily add `top-border: 0;` to the `<td>` style attribute.

Comment: This worked for me, too. I guess I wasn't aware of the minimum height in a `<tr>`. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulo Scardine :Hi, this looks good +1 for the solution, but what if I want to click on the row and the subsequent rows get expanded/collapsed ? I mean, lets say in the above example,there are 3 columns. How do we wrap all three within the tr?

Comment: @PavanSandeep: just use a div with `collapse="isCollapsed"` inside every `td` on the `tr` and Angular will shrink or expand the table row according to `isCollapsed` being true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue for angular animations on table rows.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12593

The best way to do it is shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GV9Euz5AJFllik7VhHM5?p=preview).

```
<tr ng-click="row1Open = !row1Open">
      <td>Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
      <td>{{row1Open}}</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse-row">
      <td>
        <div collapse="!row1Open">
          <div class="collapse-cell">
            Detail Row {{demo.hello}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div collapse="!row1Open">
          <div class="collapse-cell">
            abc
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div collapse="!row1Open">
          <div class="collapse-cell">
            $2.90
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```